# Open Link in the same window below button in VF page

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am looking for a solution where when I click on a button, the resulting page should open in the same window below the button. Below is my current VF page, right now the page is opening in a new tab.

```
<apex:page lightningStylesheets="true">
<style>
    body input.btn, body input.btnDisabled, body input.btnCancel {
    padding: 4px 3px;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid #dddbda;
    transition: border .15s linear;
    background-color: #0070d2;
    border-color: #0070d2;
    /* color: #fff; */
    width: 300px;
    height: 35px;
    }
</style>

<apex:form target="_self" >

        <center>
            <apex:commandButton id="one" value="Lead Page" oncomplete="openDashboard(this.id);" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <apex:commandButton id="two" value="Account Page" oncomplete="openDashboard(this.id);"/> 
        </center>
        <br/>
</apex:form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function openDashboard(clicked_id) {
    if(clicked_id.includes('one')){
        window.open("Lead URL");
    }else if(clicked_id.includes('two')){
        window.open("Account URL");
    } 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to ensure that the link is opened in the same tab, you should use

`window.location.replace()`

See the example below:

`window.location.replace("http://www.w3schools.com");`

Source -  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use below syntax to open the url in the same page.

```
window.open("<URL>",'_self');
```

Check the window.open method and its parameters at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Another solution would be to use replace as suggested by Sahil (upvoted). I cannot think of cons and pros of any approach so its upto you how you would like to go.