# How to load the same window instead of opening a new window on click on custom button?

Tags: case, custom-button, page-layout, record-type, list-view

I have created a custom button as New Case on case list view page. when I click on that button it open in a new tab.
I have used this :- window.open('{!URLFOR($Action.Case.NewCase,Case.Id )}');
This button should open record type selection window pop-up within same tab. How to achieve this?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). See if this answers your question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/286406/81648

Comment: Did you tried this `window.open('{!URLFOR($Action.Case.NewCase,Case.Id)}',"_self")`